# React Native app stuck in Splash screen after adding HMS Location package

Tags: react-native, huawei-mobile-services

I am trying to integrate HMS Location following the guide [here](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/HMS-Plugin-Guides-V1/integrating-sdk-0000001050041330-V1). Unfortunately, after following the last step of adding `packages.add(new RNHMSLocationPackage());` in my `MainApplication.java`, my React Native can no longer run properly, it just stucks in splash screen. Have anyone faced similar issue?